# Searching for Austrian WW2 Prisoner of War who was held in Worcestershire, England?

Tags: england, world-war-2, austria, imprisonment

I am looking for information on a World War 2 prisoner of war from Austria name Peter Schmidt who was brought to my farm in England every day to work.

I believe he went back to Austria and had a daughter named Heidi.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, "Schmidt" in all it's variants is a quite common name in Austria. How you wrote it it may be also be more common for a German person. Providing more detailed information about the person may help.

Regarding the POW camp I believe you mean "Longbridge Camp, Hampton Lovett, Droitwich, Worcester". The National Archives holds some information about POW in British hands, have a look at https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/prisoners-of-war-british-hands.